# Android: classCastException on view holder

Tags: android

I have a adapter where iam trying to retrieve the contact details into a listview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

    View view = convertView; 
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) { 
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, null); 
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.textContNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno);
    holder.textEmailId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailId); 
    view.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();


    Profile contact = listCont.get(position); 
    holder.text.setText(contact.getName()); 

    QuickContactBadge photo = (QuickContactBadge ) view.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);  
    photo.setTag(contact.getMobileNo()); 
    new LoadImage(photo).execute(contact.getMobileNo());
```

i am getting the follogin error in my log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 17:07:27.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6988): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.appright.myneighborhood.data.Profile cannot be cast to org.appright.myneighborhood.adaptor.ProfileAdapter$ViewHolder
12-19 17:07:27.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6988):     at org.appright.myneighborhood.adaptor.ProfileAdapter.getView(ProfileAdapter.java:82)
12-19 17:07:27.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6988):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1949)
12-19 17:07:27.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6988):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1228)
```

getting classcastexception near this line : holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
where i am doing wrong, Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are getting that exception because view.getTag() will return Object and you are trying to typecast it in ViewHolder

Comment: try finishing up with your `else` statement brackets

Comment: @ Shreya Shah plz suggest me what should i do

Comment: can you add a log like this: Log.i("class", view.getTag().getClass()+""); ??

Comment: @ frayab 12-19 17:33:41.490: E/AndroidRuntime(7696): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.myneigh.data.Profile cannot be cast to org.myneigh.adaptor.ProfileAdapter$ViewHolder

Comment: post the full method and `ViewHolder` too.

Comment: itz my mistake..wrongly loaded the jarfile, loading the jar file correctly worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think so return type delcare for this,

```
return view;
```

Comment: i had missed out this line in the if clause view.setTag(holder);